# Remove user from registry ACL

Tags: powershell, registry, acl

I'm trying to remove a user from a registry ACL. My code so far:

```
$regPath = "HKLM:\software\wow6432node\myapp"
$userToRemove = 'builtin\users'
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $regPath

# Loop over users and remove.
foreach ($user in $acl.Access) { 
    if ($user.IdentityReference.Value -eq $userToRemove) {
        $acl.RemoveAccessRule($user)
    }
    Set-Acl -Path $regPath -AclObject $acl
}
```

This is showing the error:

> Cannot convert argument 'rule', with value 'Builtin\USERS' for 'RemoveAccessRule' to type 'System.Security.ACcessControl.RegistryAccessRule'

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488342/how-can-i-remove-a-single-user-acl-from-a-large-set-of-folders

Comment: @MarkWragg According to the code they're already doing what I suggested in that answer. However, in that case they shouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: @user9924807 I can only reproduce the problem you describe if I change `$acl.RemoveAccessRule($user)` into `$acl.RemoveAccessRule("$user")`. Please double-check that your actual code doesn't convert the access rule object to a string at some point.